# What does this code mean "ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm still new to cpp, and I will appericate if someone can help me to understand this line of code:

```
ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));
```

This code I saw almost every single Hacker Rank challange. What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: What part of this is unclear to you?

Answer (score 22):

I say, when in doubt, simplify.

When something seems too complex and does not make sense at first glance, find ways to break it into smaller pieces that make sense to you.

```
ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));
```

can be broken into two pieces.

```
auto res = getenv("OUTPUT_PATH");
ofstream fout(res);
```

You can look up the [documentation of `getenv()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) to understand what the first line does. In your case, it returns the value of the environment variable `OUTPUT_PATH`. After the line is executed, `res` will be that value.

You can lookup [the documentation for the constructors of `ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) to understand what the second line does. In your case, it constructs an `ofstream` object using the value of the environment variable `OUTPUT_PATH`.

After that line, you can use the `fout` object to write to the stream. The output will be available in the file defined by the environment variable `OUTPUT_PATH`.

The reason that `Hacker Rank` does this is because they have 100's or 1000's of users running the same pieces of code at the same time. To make sure each run uses a unique output file they set `OUTPUT_PATH` to a unique name before running the code. This will ensure that the output will be placed into a unique file. The wrapper code on `Hacker Rank` will then compare the output from your file against the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

It's creating an output file stream with the filename of whatever the environment variable "OUTPUT_PATH" is set to.

Answer (score 0):

it's an easy stuff. It is taking the output environment path and passing 
that to the object of output stream i.e fout.

Hope you remember
ios_base -> ios -> ostream -> ofstream

As Per cppreference ,

**std::ofstream**

typedef basic_ofstream ofstream;

Output stream class to operate on files

**std::getenv**

Defined in header `cstdlib`

```
char* getenv( const char* env_var );
```

Searches the environment list provided by the host environment (the OS), for a string that matches the C string pointed to by env_var and returns a pointer to the C string that is associated with the matched environment list member.

check out your home path using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH"))
        std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
}
```

you are going to see all the paths you have set in your environment

environment has the location of the compiler or other executable stuff.