# How to take input?

Tags: php, stdin

I have started to practice coding problems ([hackerearth.com](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/codemonk-arrays-strings/algorithm/monk-and-welcome-problem/)) in `PHP` to increase my problem-solving skill.
As I saw, most of the coding problems are asked for taking input and then output the correct answer based on entered input.

> [Eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl1km.png) :   Input-
>
> 1. The first line consists of two integers N and
>    K, N being the number of elements in the array and K denotes the
>    number of steps of rotation.
> 2. The next line consists of N space
>    separated integers , denoting the elements of the array A.

Till now, I know -

```
 fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d\n", $n, $k); //takes N and K
```

But I don't know how to take an array of size N.

Please help me how to take array of size N. Then It will help me to code further. Else I  will just stuck on taking input.

### EDIT:

Please help me any PHP pro coder.

### EDIT 2:

The problem on which I am still stuck is given below -
**Coding challenge -**
Monk and Rotation
Monk loves to preform different operations on arrays, and so being the principal of Hackerearth School, he assigned a task to his new student Mishki. Mishki will be provided with an integer array A of size N and an integer K , where she needs to rotate the array in the right direction by K steps and then print the resultant array. As she is new to the school, please help her to complete the task.
[image]
[image]

#### EDIT 3 -

Problem can be found [here](https://code.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/monk-and-rotation-3-bcf1aefe/).
**What I have tried till know to solve this problem-**

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $t);
fscanf(STDIN, "%s %s\n", $n, $k);
//taking 5 numbers seperated by space.
fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d %d %d %d\n", $item1,$item2,$item3,$item4,$item5);

$arr = [$item1,$item2,$item3,$item4,$item5];
for($i = 0; $i<$k; $i++){
    array_unshift($arr, array_pop($arr));
}
echo implode(' ', $arr);
```

Comment: Please share more details. How **exactly** do you want to gather such an input? As a comma seperated list? In a do/while loop?

Comment: I have already posted a link of my problem on which I am currently stuck because of unable to take input. By the way see my `EDIT 2` to get the whole problem.

Comment: @NicoHaase Please see my problem in `EDIT 2`.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Probably, the input is a string of numbers, seperated by a space?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried `fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d\n", $n, $k);` to take input for `N` and `K` where N is size of the array. But I don't know how to take an array of size N. As given in question, they gave N=5. So I used `fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d %d %d %d\n", $a1, $a2, $a3, $a4,$a5);` to take 5 numbers. But If the value of N changes to something other than 5 then  `fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d %d %d %d\n", $a1, $a2, $a3, $a4,$a5);`  is not working. This is the main problem I am stuck on it.

Comment: The size of the array is dynamic. So elements inside the array can be up to `10 to the power 5`. I passed the first test case and its output is correct, but I failed in all other test cases because of array size is dynamic. Please let me know If you still didn't get ???

Comment: Why not read the value, and use `explode`? Much better than checking for a fixed "array" size

Comment: I used `explode(' ', readline());` but it is returning empty array. Please open  [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/) and then click on `Monk and Roation` to solve the problem by using your coding tricks...

Comment: Please share all such details by editing your question. If `fscanf` works better, why not read the entire string in through that?

Comment: atleast one time use the link which I send just above of this comment and try your code at there. you will get full detail there.

Comment: No, thanks. You should list **your** approaches to resolve the problem if you need help

Comment: @NicoHaase now please see my `EDIT 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `readline` to read in the space-separated integers, then just split at the spaces to get an array. Note that the array elements will be of type string.

```
// input string
$string = readline();

// turn into an array
$array = explode(" ", $string);
```

Comment: I have tried `$arr =  explode(' ', readline());` but it is returning empty array in hackearth. Please go to [exmaple](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/) and click on 'Monk and Rotation' to get the problem I am working on it.

Comment: Problem is very simple but I don't know how to take input in PHP.

Comment: please see my `EDIT 2` to get what is my real problem on which I am working.

Answer (score 0):

In hackerearth for PHP you can do something like this -

```
function getMyInput($n)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($n);
}

$t = fgets(STDIN);

for ($t_itr = 0; $t_itr < $t; $t_itr++) {
    $n[] = fgets(STDIN);  
}
getMyInput($n);
```

Reference link

[PHP standard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554760/php-standard-input)

[What does this code mean "ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170367/what-does-this-code-mean-ofstream-foutgetenvoutput-path)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Explanation

Use fgets to read a line from the input using STDIN (I/O reading)
then iterate from zero to the maximum provided INPUT and assign those values into a variable.
create a custom method and pass the I/O data (array variable) as an argument to make your own logic for problem-solving.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase Added reference link

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources. Explain why your code resolves the given problem, not what each operation does on its own

Comment: @NicoHaase added more detail